# Get exit code from preceding command before pipe

Tags: bash, shell, exit, node.js, tee

I have this:

```
node ${SUMAN_RUNNABLE} | tee -a run.sh.log
EXIT_CODE=$?;
```

but it looks like the exit code is always 0 because tee is providing the code not the node executable.

Is there a way to capture the exit code from the node executable in such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221870/5020949:

> There is an internal Bash variable called `$PIPESTATUS`; it’s an array
>   that holds the exit status of each command in your last foreground
>   pipeline of commands.
>
> ```
> <command> | tee out.txt ; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0
> ```
>
> Or another alternative which also works with other shells (like zsh)
>   would be to enable pipefail:
>
> ```
> set -o pipefail
> ...
> ```
>
> The first option does *not* work with `zsh` due to a little bit
>   different syntax.